# Various blockquote issues

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

I've encountered what may be a bug or few. It seems that blockquotes can't become less-nested, at least not easily.
Take the following:

> one deep
>
> > two deep
> >
> > > three deep
> > >       two deep
> > >       one deep

The code for that is:

```
> one deep
>> two deep
>>> three deep
>> two deep
> one deep
```

There should be a nice neat nesting up then nesting down, but it all gets appended to three deep instead.

I discovered this during trying to place this post: [Spatial analysis? Two layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23359/spatial-analysis-two-layers/23409#23409) (where one of the sub-nests works, but the other didn't)

My follow on question would be - Even assuming block-quotes work, are they they best way to style that sort of thing? Because they don't seem to respect single return characters.
I.e.:

```
>one
>two
>three
is actually three separate lines (look at the "edit") and this line is actually a fourth line that doesn't have any &gt; arrows at all, yet has still been subsumed.
```

...yields:

> one
>   two
>   three
>   is actually three separate lines (look at the "edit") and this line is actually a fourth line that doesn't have any > arrows at all, yet has still been subsumed.

Answer (score 8):

In Markdown, you have to insert two line breaks to cause an actual linebreak (a new paragraph, to be precise). That's not only true in blockquotes.

For example,

```
single
line break
```

gives

single
line break

and

```
> one deep

>> two deep

>>> three deep

>> two deep

> one deep
```

gives

> one deep
>
> > two deep
> >
> > > three deep
> >
> > two deep
>
> one deep

**Regarding the post you linked to:**

Mixing blockquotes and unorderered lists doesn't seem to be a good idea (in Markdown or elsewhere).

Just use the list syntax to get the indentation you want and apply a single `<blockquote>` around it:

```
>- Select by Location
- Select features from
- tick the LandPlots layer
- Source layer
 - Either:
     - The one you exported.
 - OR:
     - SoilTypes (this assumes...)
     - `make sure you tick: _Use Selected Features_`
- Spatial selection: Your choice, but usually it's the top one.
```

gives

> - Select by Location
> - Select features from
> - tick the LandPlots layer
> - Source layer
>
>   - Either:
>
>     - The one you exported.
>   - OR:
>
>     - SoilTypes (this assumes...)
>     - `make sure you tick: _Use Selected Features_`
> - Spatial selection: Your choice, but usually it's the top one.

Comment: Interesting. But If I do that on my linked post, it actually nests to two levels lower (so a >> shows at >). Similarly in that post, the `>> - OR:` after the `>>>The one you exported.` is at the right depth (but with only one return), while the last > is either at >> or 0 depth depending on how many returns. It never shows at > depth. (hopefully this is clear :-) )

Comment: Please see my edit. If I misinterpreted your intentions, let me know.

Comment: Ah. That lets me tidy up my answer anyway. Thanks! (though that's not in the documentation that you can do that - you clearly need one > on each line there) However the inconsistent down-nesting and continuation of blockquotes over multiple lines remains.

Comment: You can add a single `>` before each line. It doesn't matter if you do or not, since the Markdown parser ignores single line breaks anyway.

Comment: Useful to know. The documentation should probably reflect this.